# Unable to assign property Text. string expected, got Instance

Tags: lua, roblox

I was making random text script (dont mind the sounds thing) and I got this error: Unable to assign property Text. string expected, got Instance.

```
while thing == true do
    wait(math.random(3, 12))
    local txts = game.ServerStorage.CallTexts:GetChildren()
    local Choices = script:GetChildren()
    local RandomIndex = math.random(1, #Choices)
    local RandomSound = Choices[RandomIndex]
    local RandomTextIndex = math.random(1, #txts)
    local RandomText = Choices[RandomTextIndex]
    RandomSound:Play()
    game.Workspace["Talking Ben's Room"].furniture.desk.phone["De Text"].BilBord.toxt.Text = RandomText
    wait(RandomSound.TimeLength) 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Text` should be a string. `RandomText` is an Instance. Like the error told you. What type are the `Choices`, e.g. the children of `CallTexts`? Do they have a getter/toString?

If they are `StringValue`s you will need `RandomText.Value`

If they are [`TextLabel`s](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TextLabel) (your case), you will need `RandomText.ContentText`

Comment: No, they aren't values, they are textlabels

Comment: Same solution with different field. I updated my answer. Take a look at the linked docu.

Comment: I think, I need to use other script for it, because there was another script (random sound script) and for some reason it was searching ContentText inside Sound: ContentText is not a valid member of Sound "Workspace.Choices.CallManager.No"