# Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got Instance

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Something is wrong with the value. It says 'Unable to assign property Value. string expected, got Instance'. Did anyone know how to fix it?

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local RankStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("RankStore")
local players = game:GetService("Players")

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local UserId = Player.UserId
    local Rank = RankStore:GetAsync(UserId)
    
    if Rank == nil then
        Rank = "-"
        RankStore:SetAsync(UserId, Rank)
    end
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", Player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local Rank = Instance.new("StringValue", leaderstats)
    Rank.Name = "Rank"
    Rank.Value = Rank
    
    Rank.Changed:Connect(function(NewRank)
        RankStore:SetAsync(UserId, NewRank)
    end)
end)
```

Comment: You already asked similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173268/unable-to-assign-property-text-string-expected-got-instance. It's still the same issue, don't assign Instances when a string is expected. `Rank.Value = Rank` what is your intention here in the first place?

Comment: @Luke100000 What do you mean? I want do make when player will join he will automatically set the leaderstat's value to '-', but it will not put in any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through what's happening. First

```
local Rank = RankStore:GetAsync(UserId)
```

You define `Rank` as the result from your datastore lookup. Then

```
if Rank == nil then
    Rank = "-"
    RankStore:SetAsync(UserId, Rank)
end
```

If you didn't get anything back, likely because it's a new player, you set `Rank` to the string `"-"`. At this point, the value of `Rank` could be `"-"` or whatever was saved there previously.

```
local Rank = Instance.new("StringValue", leaderstats)
Rank.Name = "Rank"
```

You shadow the previous value with a new definition; you create a StringValue instance and assign it to `Rank`. At this point, when you ask for the variable `Rank`, it is pointing at the StringValue.

```
Rank.Value = Rank
```

Here, your code throws the error. You are trying to assign the StringValue's Value property (which is supposed to be a string) to the Instance of the StringValue itself.

To fix this, you need to be more careful in how you name your variables, and avoid naming collisions. The most simple solution is to rename the StringValue to something else :

```
local RankStatsValue = Instance.new("StringValue", leaderstats)
RankStatsValue.Name = "Rank"
RankStatsValue.Value = Rank

RankStatsValue.Changed:Connect( function(NewRank)
```